# in gsp even I change latitude and longitude emuletar still show the same location why it reacts like that? and how I correct it?

Tags: android, gps

this my code and it loade normali but when I change latitude and longitude it not show the corresponding location. I use emulatar to test the programe. I change latitude and longitude by using emulator control.

```
package com.rumes.gspuse;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Main extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MapView map=(MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);

        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        final MapController controller=map.getController();
        LocationManager manager=(LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener listner=new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                controller.setCenter(new GeoPoint((int)location.getLatitude(), (int)location.getLongitude()));

            }
        };

        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,listner);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is _emuletar_? Please link to it if it's a third party. Unless it's another typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need latitudeE6 and longitudeE6, that's why you don't see any difference in map!

```
if(location != null) // avoid crash (check for null)..
    controller.setCenter(new GeoPoint((int)(location.getLatitude() * 1E6), (int)(location.getLongitude() * 1E6)));
```

Comment: As OP isn't on Stack Overflow anymore, please edit and update the Question to clarify if _emuletar_ is a typo or a third-party product (in the later case, please link to it). Thank you. I may also suggest to simplify the code of the question (remove the stubs? remove the extra imports?) or eventually vote to close it.